# MUI - Datetime picker new value to be captured and set when user clicks accept

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui, datetimepicker, mui-x-date-picker

```
import React from 'react'
import { Stack, Typography } from '@mui/material'
import { DateTimePicker } from '@mui/x-date-pickers/DateTimePicker'
import { renderTimeViewClock } from '@mui/x-date-pickers/timeViewRenderers'
import dayjs, { Dayjs } from 'dayjs'

interface ResponsiveDateTimePickerProps {
  value: Dayjs | null
  maxDateTime: Dayjs | null
  minDateTime: Dayjs | null
  disabled?: boolean
  label?: string
  onAccept: (date: Dayjs | null) => void
}

const ResponsiveDateTimePicker: React.FunctionComponent<
  ResponsiveDateTimePickerProps
> = ({ value, maxDateTime, minDateTime, disabled, label, onAccept }) => {
  type textFieldSizes = 'small' | 'medium' | undefined
  type actionBarOptions = 'today' | 'accept'

  const dateTimePickerProps = {
    viewRenderers: !label
      ? {
          hours: renderTimeViewClock,
          minutes: renderTimeViewClock,
          seconds: renderTimeViewClock,
        }
      : undefined,
    value,
    maxDateTime: maxDateTime || undefined,
    minDateTime: minDateTime || undefined,
    onAccept: (date: unknown) => {
      if (dayjs.isDayjs(date)) {
        onAccept(date as Dayjs)
      } else {
        onAccept(null)
      }
    },
    format: 'DD MMMM YYYY, h:mm a',
    disabled,
    slotProps: {
      actionBar: {
        actions: ['today' as actionBarOptions, 'accept' as actionBarOptions],
        sx: { padding: 0 },
      },
      textField: () => ({
        size: 'small' as textFieldSizes,
        InputProps: {
          placeholder: value ? '' : 'Forever',
          sx: {
            height: '40px',
          },
          slotProps: {
            input: {
              sx: {
                height: '21px !important',
                fontSize: '14px !important',
                padding: '8.5px 30px !important',
              },
            },
          },
        },
      }),
    },
  }

  return (
    <Stack direction="row" alignItems="center">
      {label && (
        <Typography
          variant="subtitle1"
          sx={{ minWidth: '120px' }}
          paddingRight={0}
        >
          {label}
        </Typography>
      )}
      <DateTimePicker {...dateTimePickerProps} />
    </Stack>
  )
}

export default ResponsiveDateTimePicker
```

So when I am using this Datetime picker and I render both the date and time portions in the picker, I have noticed this flow:

- User clicks the picker display
- User gets prompted to select date
- User gets prompted to select hour (then can select am or pm here too)
- User gets prompted to select minutes (then can select am or pm here too as well)

Now the problem is that, I would like the user to click Accept and then only I want to call `onAccept` function. However, the picker treats the user selecting the minutes as an "Accept" (I understand that the minute selection is the last activity within the datetime picker flow)

How do I force the function call to be made explicitly when the user clicks "Accept" and not just by selecting the minutes value. Ideally, I want to give the user the ability to go back and make changes to the hour value if they need to and hence the picker just treating the minute selection as an "Accept" is disrupting that flow.

All help and a point to the right direction would be super appreciated.
Thanks team.

Answer (score 1):

You can use
`closeOnSelect`

**If true, the popover or modal will close after submitting the full date.**

Default: `true` for desktop, `false` for mobile (based on the chosen wrapper and `desktopModeMediaQuery` prop).

Here you can check [DateTimePicker API](https://mui.com/x/api/date-pickers/date-time-picker/#DateTimePicker-prop-closeOnSelect) Documentation